When building drainage from a downspout to a catch basin on a four inch drag, why not 3 inch PVC?
I've seen numerous people build direct-connect systems to downspouts. They're all using 4 inch to the downspout. This doesn't make sense to me: why use 4 inch pipe instead of three inch pipe, ESPECIALLY when you're connecting multiple rain gutters in the run to the street when the main drag is only 4 inches (all a big box store sells in the USA).
I have 4 runs from rain gutters feeding my main street run. Currently I'm doing a 3 inch from rain gutter to a 4x4x3 wye, immediately to a catch basin which continues channeling the four inch main drag. My goal is to keep the water moving fast until it gets to the catch basin.
I'm just wondering if there is a down side to this approach and why all examples I see use only 4-inch-pvc or corrugated for backyard drainage ignoring 3 inch entirely. It's cheaper, and it would seem better fit for branches on a drainage trunk.

3" drains will readily clog faster from wind blown leaves and twigs than a 4" drain line. If you run more than one downspout from different locations, and with the minimal slope that is usually placed on the inground pipe, a 3" line will easily get over powered by the amount of rain passing through it during a heavy rain. If there are more than 3 downspouts going into 1 main line, I would certainly bump the size up to 6" at that point if not sooner.

And 3" is probably less tolerant of bellies in the pipe and poor grade.
